# Firebase Firestore Rules: Allow read/write only if auth.id == request.data.id

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using these rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // Documents can only be read or written by authenticated users
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid;
    }
  }
}
```

From my understanding, this should mean: "Allow read or write operations ONLY IF the user is authenticated and their `uid` matches the `uid` of the document they are reading or writing".

Yet, I continually get `permission-denied` errors.

This is the code I am using (Dart/Flutter):

```
  static FirebaseFirestore instance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  static CollectionReference colRef = instance.collection('someCollection');
```

With this wrapper method (updated):

```
Future<void> updateData() async {
    final uid_ = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final data = {'uid': uid_};
    await colRef.doc(uid_).set(data);
}
```

Basically, I am passing the user `uid` to the `updateData` function, and ensuring the document has the same `uid` so it conforms with the rules.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Things that I have tried:

1. Ensured that the user was authenticated and that the correct `uid` was being passed to the wrapper function.
2. Used the `set` method instead of the `update` method to avoid any issues if the document does not yet exist.
3. Appended the `uid` to the `data` map after learning more about the `resource` object.
4. Toggled the rules between `request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid` and `request.auth.uid == resource.id`.
5. Changed the rule to only be `request.auth != null`, which ended up working as expected, but is a bit too broad for my comfort zone. Yet, this is proof that the user is authenticated. I just need a way to compare the `auth.uid` with either the `document.id` or `uid` within the data map object.
6. Changed the wrapper method to explicitly use `FirebaseAuth.instance`.

The specific error:

`flutter: [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.`

Comment: The code you shared so far does not yet access Firestore in any way. Please edit your question to show the minimal-but-complete code that we can run to reproduce the problem. It also helps if you then prove in your code how it meets the requirements of your security rules, e.g. by logging the UID of the current user.

Comment: I imagine that the code is accessing Firestore, otherwise why would it raise the `permission-denied` exception every time it is being called? Furthermore, I cannot paste my entire authentication flow and where and how the wrapper function is being called--it should work standalone since it merely wraps the Firestore `.set` method.

Comment: Thanks for all the updates. From the code you shared it's still not clear how `updateData` is called, and what value is passed for the `uid` parameter. Can you reproduce the problem in a single code-snippet, that uses `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid` for the document ID?

Comment: My authentication flow is in a separate package, I really do not want to get into that entanglement unless absolutely necessary. May I ask why you think it is the issue, especially since edit #5 (the wrapper methods work when the rules are reduced to `request.auth != null`)?

Comment: I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that shows why it's important to start from scratch when asking for help with a problem in your existing code.  --- On #5, if the user is signed in, yet the rules reject the operation, it stands to reason that you're trying to access a document for which `request.auth.uid == resource.data.uid` is not true. Logging both `uid` and `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid` in your `updateData` method will likely show this too.

Comment: What might also help is showing us a screenshot of the document you're trying to write. Your rule requires `resource.data.uid`. Does the document really have a field called `uid` with the same value as the document ID?

Comment: My point is with edit #5, authentication can be ruled out as being the problem. The wrapper method also clearly shows that the `uid` is being appended to the data map. Finally, I am in the process of uploading my code to literally use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`, and it is resulting in the same error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am literally just trying to write a map that contains a key called 'uid'--and it is failing with that exception. Do you really need a screenshot of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key was that you're trying to **write** the `uid` field for the first time.

Your rules now do this:

```
resource.data.uid
```

The `resource` here refers to the document as it exists **before** the current operation, which doesn't seem to have the `uid` value yet.

If you want to refer to the document as it'll exist after the write operation (if that write operation is allowed), use:

```
request.resource.data.uid
```

Also see the documentation on the [`resource` and `request.resource` variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation).

Comment: Thank you, I knew we could get through this without any screenshots.